# org.springframework.session.MapSession; incompatible types for field creationTime

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm having issues on our staging environment, I am unable to reproduce on develop, and can't seem to find any resource on what is going on. It feels like it occurred out of the blue and I've been attempting things and googling for days to no avail.

Stack Trace

```
    2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   2022-06-21 12:27:07.309 WARN 1 --- [ration.thread-1] c.h.m.i.o.MapClearExpiredOperation : [10.4.0.236]:5700 [dev] [3.12.12] Missing responseHandler for com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapClearExpiredOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=881778366, partitionId=69, replicaIndex=0, callId=0, invocationTime=-1 (1969-12-31 23:59:59.999), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=9223372036854775807, expirationPercentage=10}

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.session.MapSession; incompatible types for field creationTime

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.SerializationUtil.handleException(SerializationUtil.java:70)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:193)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.Records.tryStoreIntoCache(Records.java:153)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.record.Records.getValueOrCachedValue(Records.java:120)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractRecordStore.removeIndex(AbstractRecordStore.java:173)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.evict(DefaultRecordStore.java:409)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractEvictableRecordStore.getOrNullIfExpired(AbstractEvictableRecordStore.java:239)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractEvictableRecordStore.evictExpiredEntriesInternal(AbstractEvictableRecordStore.java:157)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.AbstractEvictableRecordStore.evictExpiredEntries(AbstractEvictableRecordStore.java:102)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.MapClearExpiredOperation.run(MapClearExpiredOperation.java:67)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.spi.Operation.call(Operation.java:170)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.call(OperationRunnerImpl.java:210)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:199)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:147)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:125)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:110)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.springframework.session.MapSession; incompatible types for field creationTime

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.matchFields(ObjectStreamClass.java:2391)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getReflector(ObjectStreamClass.java:2286)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:788)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2062)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1744)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:84)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.JavaDefaultSerializers$JavaSerializer.read(JavaDefaultSerializers.java:77)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.StreamSerializerAdapter.read(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:48)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   at com.hazelcast.internal.serialization.impl.AbstractSerializationService.toObject(AbstractSerializationService.java:187)

2022-06-21T09:27:07.309-03:00   ... 14 common frames omitted
```

What could possibly be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing the issue by ensuring no conflicts with Hazelcast dependencies  were occurring by excluding sub dependency pull-downs in my pom.xml and completely rebooting the EC2 instance that was running the server, it appears the error has has since subsided and everything is functioning properly.